# Handling Return Code 500 in .NET Web Services using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, asp.net-web-api, postman, retrofit

I have been working on a .NET web service that I developed and currently have it hosted on a local Windows server. In order to access it, I substituted "localhost" with the corresponding IP address. Unfortunately, I'm encountering a 500 response as a result. Since I'm new to Android API development, I'm unsure about the necessary steps to resolve this issue. I want to ensure that both my actual mobile device and desktop are connected to the same network, and I have verified that the IP address is up to date in case it has changed (as it is an office network). Any suggestions or advice on how to troubleshoot this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**ApiServices.java**

```
public interface ApiService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("ApiTest/Webservice1.asmx?op=RegVerification")
    Call<VerificationResponse> verifyRegistration(@Field("EmpID_In") String empId);

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("ApiTest/Webservice1.asmx?op=RegFinal")
    Call<String> registerFinal(@Field("AndroidID_In") String androidId, @Field("Pin_In") String pin, @Field("EmpID_In") String empId);
}
```

**HomeFragment.java**

```
 // Create Retrofit instance
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://192.168.68.158/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        // Create the ApiService
        apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);


 // Method to verify registration
    private void verifyRegistration(String empId) {
        Call<VerificationResponse> call = apiService.verifyRegistration(empId);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<VerificationResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<VerificationResponse> call, Response<VerificationResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    VerificationResponse verificationResponse = response.body();
                    List<String> data = verificationResponse.getData();
                    String error = verificationResponse.getError();

                    if (data != null) {
                        // Handle successful response
                        for (String value : data) {
                            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Data:" + value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else if (error != null) {
                        // Handle error response
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Error:" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    // Handle API error
                    Log.e(TAG, "API request failed. Response code: " + response.code());
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "API request failed. Response code:" + response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<VerificationResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                // Handle the API call failure
                Log.e(TAG, "API request failed: " + t.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "API request failed:" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

**network_security_config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.68.140</domain>
    </domain-config>

</network-security-config>
```

Yesterday, I encountered an unusual situation with the base URL and endpoints. In the morning, when I attempted to test the base and endpoint URLs using Postman, I received a satisfactory 200 OK response. However, in the evening, I started receiving a 500 response instead. I attempted various troubleshooting methods to rectify the issue but was unsuccessful. Eventually, I found a solution that resolved the problem.

**Postman**

in the Body>raw  i added this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <RegVerification xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <EmpID_In>10001</EmpID_In>
    </RegVerification>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

in the Headers i modify Content-Type

and added this value `text/xml; charset=utf-8`